# Почему ошибка в параметре типа ссылка?

Tags: c++, ссылки

```
class m {
public:

    int n;
    m(int n) :n(n) {};
    m(m& nn) {
        n = nn.n;
    }
    m operator=(m& ex);
};

m m::operator=(m& ex) {
    this->n = ex.n;
    return n;
}

m f() {
    m k(8);
    return k;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, m& ex) {
    os << ex.n<<endl;
}

int main() {
    m m1(1), m2(2);

    m1 = f();//вернулся тип m, а дальше просто как обычная передача
             //параметра по ссылке, чтобы не занимать место
    cout << m1;
    
}
```

почему ошибка=бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "m" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

есть же такое

```
int foo(int& v){
++v;}

int main(){
int x=9;
foo(x)// здесь же тоже не ссылочный тип 

}
```

Comment: Потому что выражение, относящееся к категории rvalue (безымянный объект, возвращаемый функцией), не может использоваться для инициализации lvalue ссылки на изменяемый объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m1 = f();
```

Здесь вызывается оператор присваивания, у вас имеющий вид

```
m m::operator=(m& ex) {
    this->n = ex.n;
    return n;
}
```

Заметим, что ваша функция `m f()` возвращает значение (временное) типа `m`. А объявление оператора присваивания ясно говорит, что при присваивании присваиваемый аргумент может изменяться, он не константный. То, что он не изменяется — это неважно, важно, что своим `(m& ex)` вы оставляете такую возможность.

Чтобы было понятнее, представьте себе, что это `int`, функция возвращает, например, `2`, но при присваивании это 2 должно изменяться. Но ведь переменной, которая бы хранила двойку, просто нет! Так понятнее?

Вот если бы вы объявили (оставим возврат еще одного временного объекта `m` после присваивания на ваше усмотрение, заметим только, что это лишает вас возможности использовать цепочку присваивания `a = и = сё)

```
m m::operator=(const m& ex)
```

то тогда дело другое.

В примере с `int` дело другое:

```
int foo(int& v) { ++v; }

int main(){
    int x=9;
    foo(x);
}
```

`x`, *будучи переменной*, запросто превращается в ссылку. А вот попробуйте вызвать здесь `foo(4)` — и вы увидите, что это не работает. Или хотя бы `foo(foo(x))`.

Формальный ответ вам дал user7860670 в комментариях, я же постарался просто расписать его понятнее.

Comment: не очень понятно тут "Заметим, что ваша функция m f() возвращает значение (временное) типа m", почему значение временное? из-за аргумента оператора = или как? Как я понимаю, мы в функции как бы на выходе создаем где-то в памяти безымянный объект типа м, который копирует в себя переменную из функции и ее возвращает, то есть мы просто вернули безымянный объект, но этот объект лежит же где-то в памяти```m f() {
    m k(8);
    return k;// создаем объект безымянный m и в него кладем к, безымянный и возвращаем
}```

Comment: Рассуждение свернуло куда-то не туда. Возвращаемый временный объект существует и вполне себе доступен для изменения, например у класса же можно без проблем вызвать модифицирующий метод. Другое дело, что модифицировать временный объект во внешней функции мало смысла потому что потом его модифицированное состояние можно будет использовать разве что в деструкторе, а простой встроенный тип - вообще никак.

Comment: @user7860670 Да, излишнее упрощение для понимания ни к чему хорошему не приводит, согласен...

Answer (score 2):

Аргумент `m & ex` в `m operator=(m& ex);` может быть предоставлен только объектом со стабильным временем жизни **lvalue**. А возвращаемое значение функции `m f()` возвращает **всегда** временное значение **rvalue**.
Ссылки на эти типы несовместимы и надо отдельно писать разные функции. Вариант универсальности будет если аргумент константный.

Только для **lvalue** :

```
m operator=(m & ex);
```

Только для **rvalue** :

```
m operator=(m && ex);
```

Для всех :

```
m operator=(m const & ex);
```